# AIR - Get SoftKeyboard Screen Size

Tags: android, ios, mobile, air

In my AIR mobile application I am trying to resize my application when the softkeyboard is activated so that the bottom of my application will not be covered by the keyboard. From what I have read this is suppose to be the default behavior but I have never been able to get it to work and I have tried everything I have found online, instead the keyboard overlays ontop of the application.

I then decided I would resize my application myself based on the height and y position of the softkeyboard only to find out that the built in AIR methods for determining the height and y position of the keyboard are not correct (YAY). I even tried using a 3rd party ANE for determining the screen height by FreshPlanet and their code does not always return correct values either. I feel like this shouldn't be that hard to figure out but I am stuck. Please help!

**TLDR**:
How can I resize my application to be the remaining screen space when the softkeyboard is activated?

Answer (score 0):

What  renderMode are you using? (in manifest.xml) I found that only `cpu` is working to get the correct keyboard height.
Also try to set softKeyboardBehavior to none:     `<softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>`